# Visual Studio , C# , .Net установщик EXE

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework

Возник вопрос, мы 4 года уже изучаем на парах C# , пишем небольшие программки, используем разные фреймворки и т.д, но дело до доработки проектов до готового решения с установкой так и не дошло. Даже понятия не имею, что делать с проектом, которые просто находится в папке. Немного погуглил и узнал, что можно создавать установщик через InstallShield, но если я использую базу SQL, то как мне быть?Ведь не смогут обычные пользователи (к примеру кассиры) сами ставить базу и подключать все это каждый раз. Направьте меня в правильное направление, что нужно изучать, чтобы дорабатывать проекты до конца с нормальным установщиком.

Comment: Если приложение - клиент, то зачем вам ставить базу? Обычно база, это отдельный "пакет", который нужен системному администратору или тому, кто будет настраивать серверную часть. В клиенте нужно всего лишь выдать окно с настройкой подключения. Вам же не ставит какой то скажем Steam или клиент WebMoney на компьютер SQL, нет, они просто просят ваши учетные данные.

Comment: То есть, если я разрабатываю, к примеру систему управления Отелем или систему для учета продуктов ( для которых база нужна обязательно) то всегда придется перед установкой настраивать базу и подключать все вручную?

Comment: Обычно есть сервер, некая центральная точка к которой подключаются все клиенты. 1 сервер = ~ бесконечно клиентов. Вы же не будете отдавать некие "секретные" данные вашего отеля из базы простым сотрудникам. То есть достаточно 1 раз настроить сервер и подключать сколько угодно клиентов.

Answer (score 0):

Можете посмотреть в сторону WIX TOOLSET. Это аналог InstallShield, только беслатный. Можно прописать каждый шаг. Вы можете распаковать базу данных и подключить к серверу. Правда, этот шаг подразумевает, что сам сервер у Вас уже установлен. Если Ваша система не требует центрального сервера и Вы можете хранить Ваши данные локально на компьютере, рекомендую посмотреть в сторону Sql Lite и подобных систем. С определенной версии в Visual Studio появился свой собстенный упаковщик приложений. В английской версии эта команда называется "publish"